# Kotlin - how to get rid of this compiler error?

Tags: kotlin

I have this class

```
data class Properties( val actionBarColor : Int , val fileName : String) : 
 Serializable{
var title : String = ""
var readModeOnly : Boolean = false
}
```

and this if condition

```
var properties = Properties()

if(properties?.readModeOnly){

}
```

But the compiler says , required `Boolean` found `Boolean?` . What should i do to make this work? I don't want it to be nullable.

Comment: use `val properties`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need the [safe call operator `?.`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls) if the left side is a nullable type. In this case, `properties` is non-nullable (its type is `Properties` and not `Properties?`), so you can just leave the operator off, and access the `readModeOnly` property directly:

```
var properties = Properties()

if (properties.readModeOnly) {

}
```

---

Update as per the comment below:

If `properties` *is* nullable, then `properties?.readModeOnly` will return a `Boolean?` (since it will return `null` if `properties` itself is `null`). This means the expression can evaluate to three values now: `true`, `false`, or `null`.

If you consider `null` to be `false`, you can use this `if` check:

```
if (properties?.readModeOnly == true) {

}
```

Or if `null` is considered `true`, although this seems counter-intuitive:

```
if (properties?.readModeOnly != false) {

}
```

Comment: Its actual definition is nullable.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `?.let{}`

```
properties?.let {
    val readModeOnly = it.readModeOnly
    ...
}
```